# How to make text fill table cell?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm using an asp.net table. The first column of the table contains captions of each row of data. There are different amounts of words in each caption. I want the first letters of each caption to be aligned one above the other at the beginning edge of the caption cells(left side in ltr) and the last letters of each caption to be aligned one above the other at the end edge of the caption cells(right side in ltr). I want the spacing to effect the word spacing but not the letter spacing or font size. I **don't** want stretching of the font.

I prefer that all the first words of the caption be aligned to the beginning of the cell and the last word only aligned to the end of the cell. But equal spreading of all the words is also possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 15px;
}

td {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: justify;
}

    td::after {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }

span.left {
    float: left;
}

span.right {
    float: right;
}
```

.NET table with text filling all cell:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Phrase 1 with words</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>Phrase 2 with words</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

.NET table with text to the left and to the right:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <span class="left">Word Left 1</span>
            <span class="right">Word Right 1</span>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <span class="left">Word Left 2</span>
            <span class="right">Word Right 2</span>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: Your first answer with the span float left and right worked for me well. I would mark it as an answer. Please show both as options.

Comment: Could explain how the new option with the td::after works?

Comment: I will try: the `::after` pseudo element inserts an empty content after the `td` of 100% width. As the `text-align` is justified and there's a block of 100% width, the text is justified as if the text fills all the `td`.

Comment: It's as if the `td` was shrunk because of the block so the text fills all the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property `text-align:justify` should be appropriate for your needs

> `justify` - Content spaces out such that as many blocks fit onto one
>   line as possible and the first word on that line is along the left
>   edge and the last word is along the right edge.

Read more about the `text-align` property [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/)

Comment: I'm using an asp.net table and I tried setting the horizontal align to justify and I also tried making a css Class like this:   td.justify{
            text-align:justify;
        } and set the table CssClass property to that but neither worked.